# Ruby crawl site, add URL parameter

Tags: ruby, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl a site and **append a URL parameter to each address** before hitting them. Here's what I have so far:

```
 require "spidr"
    Spidr.site('http://www.example.com/') do |spider|
      spider.every_url { |url| puts url }
    end
```

But I'd like the spider to hit all pages and append a param like so:

- example.com/page1?var=param1
- example.com/page2?var=param1
- example.com/page3?var=param1

UPDATE 1 - 
Tried this, not working though, errors out ("405 method not allowed") after a few iterations:

```
require "spidr"
require "open-uri"
Spidr.site('http://example.com') do |spider|
  spider.every_url do |url|
    link= url+"?foo=bar"
    response = open(link).read
  end
end
```

Comment: You would just add the param to the array of URLs... Have you tried anything?

Comment: Right that did occur to me, but then what? After I create an array of properly formatted URLs, run that back thru spidr?

Comment: Sounds good to me. Try it

Comment: Updated my post with my attempt. There must be a better way to do this. It seems to work for 20 or 30 requests, then I get a 405 method not allowed. Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on Spidr, I just grabbed a CSV of the URLs I needed from Google Analytics, then ran thru those. Got the job done.

```
require 'csv'
require 'open-uri'

CSV.foreach(File.path("the-links.csv")) do |row|
    link = "http://www.example.com"+row[0]+"?foo=bar"
    encoded_url = URI.encode(link)
    response = open(encoded_url).read
    puts encoded_url
    puts
end
```